# force:recordData fetch the fields from controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Ho to get the force:recordData fields in javascript controller?

cmp:

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<aura:attribute name="contact" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleContact" type="Object"/> 
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.createRecord}"/>

<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>    
<force:recordData aura:id="contactRecordLoader"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  fields="Id,Name,FirstName,AccountId"
                  targetRecord="{!v.contact}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleContact}"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  />
```

JS:

```
({
    createRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
        var con = component.get("v.simpleContact");       
        console.log("THis is contact FirstName "+con.FirstName);       
    }
})
```

**Error:**
I am getting null "console.log("THis is contact FirstName "+con.FirstName);   "

Comment: @sfdcfox worked...:) thank you.

     var con = component.get("v.contact"), param;
            param = { sobjectType: 'Contact', Id: con.fields.Id.value, FirstName: con.fields.FirstName.value };       
            console.log(param.FirstName);

Answer (score -1):

Did you include  force:hasRecordId interface?  force:hasRecordId interface provides the implicit recordID attribute which is used by  force:recordData to fetch the record and populate the targetfields attribute.

If the recordID is not provided, the force:recordData is used for generating new record or other functions.